# Run Single App on XP

Tags: windows

Is it possible to configure an **Windows xp to run a single application** of dotnet?

Comment: I want to run a winform application on windows xp with .net framework 3.5. I want that; On Bootup of pc only my application will show to the user. And on on exit, windows will be shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The operating system itself runs many different applications just to perform its basic functions.

If you're talking about preventing the user from interacting with all other applications, that's something you can configure using Group Policy. This is an infrastructure feature built into Windows that allows system administrators to exercise precise control over the abilities of individual user accounts.

You can easy configure a policy to prevent users from launching applications other than those you explicitly allow. This is not, however, something that you can write code yourself to do.

Help on configuring Group Policy is available from your system administrator, or from the kind folks over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). However, if you decide to ask a question there, you will need to provide a *lot* more details about what exactly you're trying to configure, what operating system you're running, and any other requirements that might be important.

Comment: I want to run a winform application on windows xp with .net framework 3.5. I want that; On Bootup of pc only my application will show to the user. And on on exit, windows will be shutdown.

Comment: Computer Config -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Software Restriction Policies. Then right-click and select "Create New Policies".